# Bootstrap collapse panel is not closing after being opened

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hope You're Well.I have a bootstrap collapse panel.the issue i am facing is with the collapse, it is opening when clicked but not closing.the code for which goes like this.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12 ">
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
                <h3 class="box-title">
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:lblPageHeader %>" /></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-group">
                <div class="panel panel-default">

                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo" aria-hidden="True">Filter</button>

                        </h4>

                    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
                        <div class="panel-body">
```

below are the fields which should be displayed in collapsed followed by closing divs.

Any help in this regard, would be highly appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: I added the missing divs and seems to work. https://www.bootply.com/DfXScZdjEE

Comment: Uses collapse.js and requires the transitions plugin. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse

Comment: this issue usually arises due to conflict of javascript .I  removed the plugins from the current page as the same functionality is carriedout by these two <script src="/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script> in the master page.

Comment: Thanks to this post I looked and I had 2 calls to jQuery. Life saver. I was expecting to loose many hours tracking this down. Time for a cup of coffee thanks to you! Shukraan habibi (if that is not tooooooo racist :-) )

Answer (score 0):

you should change the order of scrpits in your index.html
and make them like this Order

```
script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
```